# How do I calculate ln[x]=-2.30

Tags: logarithms

Like what buttons in my Ti-Nspire do I press. What are the steps.

I'm doing chemical calculations and working on first and second order rates. And I'm stuck in ln[Ao]=-2.30

Comment: Okay. Yes. Possibly. I know a little about ln. But hey thanks for being a troll. Feel free never to comment on my question again.

Comment: This should help: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Comment: I'm just looking for a quick answer here.

Comment: What do the square brackets stand for?

Comment: Concentration of a given time but I suppose you can rid of those and it'll be ln(x) = -2.30

Comment: Are you trying to find an explicit solution for $[A_0]$?  $$[A_0]=\cdots$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't own a TI Nspire but i used these steps to solve it using calc.exe:

Solve the equation by rewriting in exponential form using the definition of a logarithm, then simplifying you get
x=1/(e^(2.3))
= approximately 0.10025884

Comment: Thank you!!!! That's all I needed.

Comment: Pathology science major here by the way